# How to run external Python script within ADO pipeline that is not within the same repo

Tags: python, c#, .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have written a scanning tool in python to be run on PR for all our repos, but I am not sure what the best approach is to generalize the usage of this code with all our individual pipelines. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

I have considered using the "Python Script" task in the pipeline, but it seems to be tailored to scripts within the same repo.

I have considered using an exe but am unsure if this will be too rigid in terms of future changes to the scanning tool itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use "Python Script" task to run python script file in another repo within the same organization, maybe you could try to add the task as a part of a template then run the template in your current repo pipeline:

Please see whether the following steps could do some help:

1.For example, here I have a simplest python file called 'python2' in repo 'store python file'

[image]

2.Create a template with task Python Script and the file path directs to 'python2'

[image]

```
steps:
- checkout: template # the 'store python file' repo alias name in main azure-pipeline yaml
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'filePath'
    scriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/python2'
```

3.Go to current repo and pipeline, add pr trigger and use the template created above:

```
pr:
  branches:
    include: 
    - main # modify as needed
  paths:
    include:
    - README.md # modify as needed
variables:
  acceptanceTestsRepoName: 'template' #the repo alias for 'store python file, you could change to whatever you want'

resources:
  repositories:  
  - repository: template #the same with the above
    name: {project name}/store python file #the real name of the repo
    type: git 
    ref: main # modify as needed

stages:
  - stage: A   
    displayName: AA
    jobs:
    - job: AAA
      displayName: AAAA
      pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
      steps:
      - template: 'template1@${{variables.acceptanceTestsRepoName}}'
```

Then after it was triggered and run, you are supposed to get things like this:

[image]